# run method from actionbar icon from mainactivity

Tags: android

I have the below method in `main_activity` that is launched when I clicked from a `button`. I am new to android so please if you can help me. I want to place this method to a another activity called `activity2` and run from it an icon from action bar. so inside `onOptionsMenuselected` in my main_activity I want to place `activity2.onclick();`

this main activity .. this works

```
 case R.id.add:

     Toast.makeText(this, "Search for new photos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    openGallery();

    // Intent  iadd= new Intent(this,AddImage.class);
    // startActivity(iadd);
     return true;
 }


   public   void openGallery() {
          Intent gallery =   new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
             android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
          startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
       }
```

If I move opengallery() to other main activity, ill get error nullerpoint exception

```
06-11 18:20:05.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at com.example.sqlfirst.AddImage.openGallery(AddImage.java:34)
06-11 18:20:05.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at com.example.sqlfirst.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:176)
06-11 18:20:05.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2650)
06-11 18:20:05.239: E/AndroidRuntime(1841):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:373)
```

this is my new code in main_activity

```
case R.id.add:
        // AddImage adimg = new AddImage(this);
         Toast.makeText(this, "Search for new photos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new  AddImage().openGallery();

        // Intent  iadd= new Intent(this,AddImage.class);
        // startActivity(iadd);
         return true;
     }
        return true;
```

this is my second activity

```
package com.example.sqlfirst;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AddImage extends ActionBarActivity {
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;



    public AddImage() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public   void openGallery() {
          Intent gallery =   new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
             android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
          startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
       }

       @Override
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {


             DBhelper db = new DBhelper(this);
          // get image from drawable
          Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
          R.drawable.sample2);
          // convert bitmap to byte
          ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
          byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();
             db.addContact(new Contact("Main", imageInByte));

          }
          }



}
```

Comment: How ugly that would be. What are you trying to do from `Activity2`?

Comment: @shkschneider at last some one commented ... in main activity I have a code that get the image from a gallery and insert it in database .. its working fine .. now I want to improve my app and I want to get the picture from the action bar icon , so I made a new activity class (activity2) so  when I try to call activity2 from main activity I get an error .. nuller exeception , can you help please ?

Comment: If you post the stacktrace from the logcat regarding that "nuller exeception" (I guess `NullPointerException`), yes.

Comment: ok ill provide you all my code and the error hoping you can help me :d @shkschneider

Comment: I cannot guess which line is `AddImage.java:34`... Anyway, you should not `startActivity()` in another `Activity` from another `Activity`, that is nuts. I don't understand what `Activity2` does nor why it is needed "to improve" your app... Question is totally unclear.

Comment: okay ill ask you it in a simple question .. in main activity i created a method caled addimage() in another activity_example i created the method addimage because I need it . so to improve my app I decide to centralize addimage() in activity2 .. so in any activity I want to add image .. i can just call it from activity2 ... so is it clear now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to share a common method across two Activities. That is a good thing.

But to achieve that, the method should either be `static` OR you would have to make a super class that both Activities would extend.

Try first to make the method static. If not possible, put that method as `protected` in a `BaseActivity extends WhateverAndroidBaseActivityYouAreUsing` or whatever and make `Activity1 extends BaseActivity`, same for `Activity2`.

Comment: Static didnt work .. can you please show me an example or tutorial because  i have spend 2 days on it and i dndt find a soultion

Comment: You pretty much got your answer here. This website is not about tutorials. Here is the first link Google returns me: http://mindprod.com/jgloss/protectedscope.html